# how to make the boundaries of a  UITableViewCell disappear?

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is what I have right now :

[image]

I want to remove the white boundary lines . Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a grouped table view style? Also, people will be more likely to answer if you accept answers on the rest of your older questions.

Comment: @jtbandes : yes, groupedview. ok, will do that. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried non-grouped (plain)?

Comment: @jtbandes : that solves the problem to some extent...however, the problem is, in the group view each group (or section) is for a different situation and if I use non-grouped style, then its hard to distinguish between the different groups or sections. Any other way to solve my problem ?

Comment: @jtbandes : solved with header section. However, there is still a white line between rows, anyway to make that vanish ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a plain-style table view (instead of grouped) and/or set the table view's `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`.